# How do I actually start the Peer Review DLC on Portal 2?

Tags: steam, portal-2, portal-2-peer-review

I just downloaded and installed the Peer Review DLC as well as a game update for Portal 2 on PS3. How do I actually play the new co-op mode, though? When I select co-op, all it lets me choose is Co-Op Standard or Co-Op Challenge, and in both cases the only levels I have access to are the original testing courses.

Comment: I have downloaded the dlc, completed co-op, completed solo, and still there seems to be absolutely nothing appearing in menues or pillars. if anyone else is having these issues, or knows a solution contact me on mattio27@hotmail.co.uk, it would be great help because the games beginning to get on my nerves

Comment: This is not an answer. If you are also experiencing the same issue you might want  to post a comment on the question.

Comment: It's pretty subtle; I didn't notice it at first. If you've downloaded and installed the DLC, go into the co-op hub where you can see the big-screen display that shows things like steps taken. Stand in the center of the main platform and look at the board; the light bridge should be ramping down in front of you from right to left. Turn 90 degrees to the right; you should see the hanging surfaces that you portal into in order to fall on the bouncy plate. From here, you should be able to see into a hollow column on the right with a door and a couple buttons visible; put a portal in there and go!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You or your partner must already have finished the regular co-op campaign.

Once you have, another pillar will appear in the hub which you can portal into. It will have two buttons, if both of you stand on one, you will be sucked into the new DLC.

Comment: Also, once you're sucked into the next room, you need to select the new campaign using the buttons on the wall. Then the door will open and you can start the new levels.

Comment: @Adeese Yeah - which is quite exciting, as I guess it means there's room for more DLC! :)